# Issue with radio buttons while firing Validations

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i have my form with some controls as follows

`2 Radio buttons 1 Text Box, 1 Required field validator and a button`

I wrote my sample code in such a way that if one radio button is selected i will enable or disable the text box that i will have.

I am having a required field validator which was set for text box available. Now what i need is when  the control was disabled i don't want to perform the validation for this is it possible to do

Sample code

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = true;
}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

My design

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="g"
        OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" ValidationGroup="g1" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="g"
        OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ValidationGroup="g1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="g1" /></div>
</form>
```

Validation should apply only when the control was enabled

Comment: lot of similar questions are there in stackoverflow itself. try a google with this http://www.google.co.in/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=disable+required+field+validator+in+asp.net+%2B+stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators have an [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enabled.aspx) property that you can use:

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
}

protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this and works well for me

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = true;
    Button1.CausesValidation = true;
}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.CausesValidation = false;
    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```